# What class replaces the mothballed 'ClientFactory' in the javax webservice API (javax.ws.rs-api)?

Tags: java, jersey, httpclient

I want to update my javax.ws.rs-api version 21.0-m09 because it is old. However, I do not see that the `ClientFactory` exists anymore in the newer versions to do this:

```
// create the client
Client c = ClientFactory.newClient();     
String baseuri = main.getBaseRestCrmUri();
WebTarget target = c.target(baseuri);

// test web response
String msg = target.path("hello/Joe").request().get(String.class);
assertEquals("Hello Joe!", msg);
```

What happened to ClientFactory in the more recent versions?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is with the downvotes?

Comment: Thanks for asking (and solving) this question! Useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it :) Use this dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
```

And then instead of this with ClientFactory:

```
Client c = ClientFactory.newClient();
```

do this with ClientBuilder:

```
Client c = ClientBuilder.newClient();
```

Comment: Actually, FYI, the client builder is part of JAX-RS 2.0 spec and `jersey-client` is transitively dependent on this APIs `javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar`